# How to hide source code of my jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am Android developer.

I have created a .jar file from **Java project** with below steps

1. Right Click on project and select export option.
2. Selected jar file from Java folder
3. Clicked on finish. Then mysdk.jar is created on desktop.

When I pasted this jar in lib folder of **Android Project**. When I selected(ctrl + left click from mouse) any method presented in jar from AndroidProject/src/demo.java , It is showing source code of .jar file.

My requirement is to give this jar to Third Party Company **who should not read my code**.

So, I want to hide my source code of jar. but how ? Please some one help me.

I am using Android Studio.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try Proguard .......

Comment: "It is showing source code of .jar file" -- it is probably showing the decompiled version of the contents of the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the created jar file and check if only contain the class files or source file. Actually it shouldn't contain source files in jar files. If it contains , make use of jar command in shell/command line to create jar file and deliver it. Also check the new project is linked the previous project because both exists in the eclipse.

```
jar -cvf <jar file name> files to be archived
```